# PHP Going Back Folders in the URL

Tags: php

I call my PHP file from a deeply nested folder because my code is structured in modules.

I tried this:

```
define('__ROOT__', dirname(__FILE__).'../../../');
echo __ROOT__;
```

This gives me:

```
/var/www/virtual/myvirtualservername/mywebsite.com/modules/Dialog/Feedback../../
```

I cannot just use:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

That gives me:

```
/var/www/virtual/myvirtualservername/html
```

which is also the wrong folder.

Unfortunately it doesn't work and I don't have an error log on my server so I can't debug the internal server error. Requested that now from my provider.

In summary, my question is how to reach the folder I want, 
`/var/www/virtual/myvirtualservername/mywebsite.com/`?

Comment: Hah, yeah I didn't really see a question in there.

Comment: instead of `dirname(__FILE__)` use just `__DIR__`

Comment: Oh: I want to reach:
/var/www/virtual/myvirtualservername/mywebsite.com/
So either go back three folders in the first solution or go back one folder and then go into another folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is you are not adding a slash at the start of your paths. Directory values are returned without trailing slashes, e.g. `/var/www`

Modifying your first line to this should work:

```
define('__ROOT__', __DIR__.'/../../../mywebsite.com');
echo __ROOT__;
```

I replaced `dirname(__FILE__)` with `__DIR__` as mentioned in the comments. Also note that `__ROOT__` does not have a trailing slash, so you would add that when putting your file in, e.g.

```
include __ROOT__ . '/file.php';
```

I'm not exactly sure what the deal is with your document root though. It looks like the public part of the site is in `html` but the PHP code is in a directory `mywebsite.com` alongside that.

Comment: I think it may was the missing slash, it works now, thank you.

Comment: By the way, I would avoid naming constants with underscores at the beginning as those are reserved for use by the core language.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know...perhaps you can do a 'string replace' if you want it to be exact, something like the following:

```
define('__ROOT__',str_replace("/modules/Dialog/Feedback","",dirname(__FILE__)));
```

Something like this should yield the result you want.